# How can I make a Vue.draggable horizontal list?

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of images that I want to drag with draggable, tried using the `direction` tag, but it doesn't change anything, is there some way I can make the list horizontal?

```html
<div class="tier-sort">
  <draggable v-model="items" direction="horizontal">
    <div 
      v-for="item in items" 
      :key="item.id" 
      class="tier-item" 
      :style="item.image"
    >
    </div>
  </draggable>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try using css.
For me, I use bootstrap so I just added

```
 class="d-flex"
```

code here

```
    <Draggable class="d-flex" v-model="questions" group="people" item-key="id">
      <template #item="{ element }">
        <FormQuestion :question="element" :key="element.id" />
      </template>
    </Draggable>
```

[image]